# Proper way of using buttons ? (firefox bug)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering what is the proper way of using bootstrap's buttons.

What i'm trying to do is simple ajax-based form. When user fills it and clicks "Send" button, i want this button to be 'bootstrap-clicked' (i mean the clicked state from bootstrap's examples). Then, if form is send properly, i want an AJAX response which will return the button to it's normal unclicked state. So, here is my code:

**The form:**

```
<input type="submit" id="button" class="btn" data-loading-text="Loading..." value="Send"/>
```

**The javascript:**

```
$('#button').bind('click', function(){
  $(this).button('loading');
})
```

**The AJAX response:**

```
$('#button').reset();
```

And now, in Chrome everything works as it should. However, when i'm running this in Firefox i can see a really strange bug. When i click on this button, it dissapears for the moment when the mouse button is down. When i'll lose the mouse button, the bootstraps button shows again. In addition, This dissapearing thing is the only action that occurs, my JS code responsible for fireing ajax response is not working. The only chance to make it works is to double click so fast that the second click occurs before button dissapears but i think it's obvious that it can't work like that ;)

Have you any ideas what am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you're suppose to be using `data-loading-text="Loading.."` not `data-loading-state="Loading"`

Comment: oh, it was a mistake in the question body, on my website i'm using `data-loading-text`, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I'm not sure what could be doing it then cause the code looks right.. I personally switched all my `<input` tags over to use `<button` instead, and it works fine in firefox without the button disappearing.. but I'm thinking theres something else that might be messing with it cause I dont understand how it could be disappearing